# Slow down UISnapBehavior

Tags: ios7, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior, uisnapbehavior

I am using a UISnapBehavior but it is snapping too quickly for my liking. Is there a way to slow it down? Or in other words: is there a way to adjust the elasticity of the object with the point where it should snap to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to solve this by attaching the view to a `UIDynamicItemBehavior` as well and setting the `resistance` property.

```
UIDynamicItemBehavior *dynamicItemBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ view ]];
dynamicItemBehavior.resistance = 100;
[animator addBehavior:dynamicItemBehavior];
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet for this? I'm doing the same thing but not seeing an affect on speed of snap...

Comment: Ah! Nevermind, I was using values between 0 and 1, values over 1 do the trick

Comment: ya @AlfieHanssen, I'm using values of 50 and 100 right now in my app

Comment: This makes sense but for some reason it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the behaviour's `damping` property to a number > 1.0. The header says `damping` should remain in `[0.0, 1.0]` however values larger than 1.0 seem to work fine.

Comment: This may be the best way if you only want to affect the snap behavior without affecting other physics of the item being snapped. For example, if you have a velocity on the item and set the resistance high, velocity too will have less of an effect. However, sadly, when setting damping, things get screwy/wonky with the snapbehavior and I wonder if it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks, snapping with damping 10 looks nice for me